# urls.py in django throws "No module found"

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a question about urls.py in Django. I am building a blog from scratch as a way of learning Django myself. In the main urls.py file, I have specified the include path to my app's urls.py.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    (r'^', include('myblog.urls')),
)
```

In the app (called myblog), the urls.py reads as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from models import blogmodel
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^login/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^$', include('myblog.views.getLatest')),

)
```

where getLAtest is the function in my views.py. The error says ***No module named getLatest***

Here's my views.py,

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from myblog.models import blogdb

def getLatest(request):
    post = blogdb.objects.all()
    sorted_post = post.order_by('-served_date')
    return render_to_response('blogs.html', {'posts':sorted_post})
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I would advise: from myblog.views import getLatest then change your pattern into (r'^$', getLatest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong directive; `include()` is used to include another package; Django will look for a `urls.py` within the package `myblog.views.getLatest` when you use that directive.

You want to name the view itself instead:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^login/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^$', 'myblog.views.getLatest'),
)
```

Note: no `include()` is being used.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Martjin. That worked!! I am beginning to understand urls a little better now. :) Thanks for the help and support.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^login/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^$', include('myblog.views.getLatest')),
)
```

to this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^getLatest/$', 'myblog.views.getLatest'),
)
```

`include` is meant to read in another `urls.py` file, where you you are wanting to execute a specific view function.